# Sound playing in background in simulator but not on device

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to allow for my app to play sound in the background. I have this code running in the viewDidLoad():

```
do {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
        print("AVAudioSession Category Playback set")
        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
            print("AVAudioSession has been set Active")
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
```

It runs well and sets active. When running this in simulator I am able to return to the home screen and sound continues to play but when I run it on a device the sound won't play outside of the app.

The sound is being played via AVAudioPlayer every x amount of seconds.

Note: I have enabled background modes in device capabilities and checked the "Audio, Airplay and Picture in Picture" box.

Comment: Hey, when you load your sounds, have you checked the case-sensitivity of the names ? On the simulator, case-sensitivity is not a problem, but on the device it is. So if your sound is named "Poof.mp3" and you try to load "poof.mp3", it will work on the simulator but not on the device.

Comment: I'm sure, my sounds work on the app just not when outside of the app.

Comment: @arch, I am having this problem . Have you managed to find a solution?

Comment: Sadly I have not, I was not able to get sound playing in the background at all on device. Although I'm not positive I think it may have been because the app was not "active" once closed and because it was not just a long sound file being played and the sound was being made every x ticks by the app, it didn't work(I hope that makes sense).

Comment: @Arch we are having smae problem. have never seen any SO question with most unuseful answers

Answer (score 0):

If you stop playing sound at any time, iOS might not allow an app to restart playing sound when in the background.

Comment: What do you mean? The sound is played and once it is finished it replay the sound.

Answer (score 0):

In order to return to your app and have the sound continue playing, you will have to add the code into `viewWillAppear()`. When you re-open your app `viewDidLoad()` will not be called but `viewWillAppear()` will.

Comment: My problem is that the sound doesn't play when outside of my app, it works when reopening the app.

Answer (score -1):

You need to make couple of changes in plist file.

i.e. 1) Set Required background mode to App plays audio

2) set Application does not run in background to NO.

```
  NSError *setCategoryErr = nil;
  NSError *activationErr  = nil;
 [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&setCategoryErr];
 [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:&activationErr];
```

Then, you need to write these much code in AppDelegate

Now, you can easily run audio while phone screen locks or goes in background.